# What X Server requirements are associated with X11 forwarding?

Tags: x11, xforwarding

For X11 forwarding, do both the local and remote systems have to run an X server?

Can I do X11 forwarding if my remote machine is in: `runlevel 3`, meaning that no X server is running?

Comment: 1. no ; 2. yes (why haven't you tried? faster than asking)

Comment: Can you please explain both the points a little as i am with very limited environment. If possible provide the link for more info.

Comment: An X Server manages a display.

Comment: @Serge Don't do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to run the X server on your client PC where you want see the GUI/Desktop. Typically this would be on your Windows PC in most environments ofcourse you could run it on a Linux/Mac workstation to. Point is the X Server itself must run on the client pc. The Linux server needs SSH along with the X Window System installed from packages, usually it is by default. The best client software I've seen to do this is MobaXTerm. MobaXTerm is a terminal client that runs an X Server on your client PC. The cool thing about MobaXTerm is it does the X Server for you along with exports the variables when you ssh to a server, it usually just works.

A tip though, if you login to a server using a terminal client such as MobaXTerm if you su, sudo, and/or switch users you loose the environment variable named DISPLAY=hostname:X.X which is required for this to work.

To install X Window software on Linux server at least CentOS/RHEL environments, others are probably similar you can check for the following.

```
 yum groupinfo "X Window System"
 yum groupinstall "X Window System"
```

Then update /etc/ssh/sshd_config to enable X11 Forwarding for SSH then restart your sshd service.